# Gestures Builder

Tags: android, gesture

When I try to run Gestures Builder I get the following error:

**Could not load/mnt/sdcard/gestures.
Make sure you have storage available.**

- How can I fix this problem?
- When I add a gesture, where is it saved?
- How can I create multiple gestures under the same name? I want to map several gestures to the same Arabic letter.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an emulator that has an SD card, and that will solve your problem. See picture attached.[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0):

Do you dw gesture builder ? I think that it is coming with the emulator .. O_o
And you must create in the emulator and then you can access it from code.

[Gestures](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html)

Comment: i fixed this problem
what about another two question??

Comment: do you check the url?, second question: it is saved in your device, third question: No (i think)

Comment: @Beginner, how do you fix this problem?